# Electric stove - burner does not stop heating

Tags: repair, stove, electric-heat

I have an electric stove (with 2 burners) - Ufesa Professional Chef - and one burner does not stop heating - I turn (rotate) the switch for that burner, and it has no effect - I have to unplugged it to turn it off. The other works fine. What can be broken? Is it worth trying to get it repaired? It's an expensive repair?

[image]

Comment: What does not stop heating mean?  Do you have to unplugged it to turn it off or if on low it is/goes on high(no control  of heat)?  To repair or not will depend on the cost of new compared to cost of repair.  More than 50% cost of new, repairs get less likely.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It could be the switch is shorted inside. You could try to find a replacement, or **add another switch**. As a DIY repair, it should be <US$10.

Comment: If you turn the switch to off and then unplug it to get the burner off, what happens when you plug it back in (with the switch still in the off position?  Does the burner start right away, with the switch in the off position?  Or do you need to turn the switch to start it?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik OP might be able swap switch positions, depending on design, and confirm if the failure follows the switch.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it worked at one time and no changes were made, the switch contacts are welded together or if solid state control the triac shorted. If it never worked the switch may not even be connected in the circuit. You will have to open it up to check. If the switch is wired it is faulty and needs to be replaced.